# Rename only part of file

Tags: php, file, rename

So far I have it so it changes it on the website, but how would I make it change the file's name on the server?

```
foreach(glob("vacation/*.jpg") as $image) {
  $tmpName = explode("_", $image);
  $tmpName = explode("~", $tmpName[1]);
  $md5 = md5($tmpName[0]);
  print "<p>{$md5}</p>";
}
```

This is what I have so far, it takes `IMG_0401~timestamp.jpg` and on the website shows it as `IMG_99f97481f8214da999e3ccbe116f5334~timestamp.jpg`

I want to actually rename the file to that

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP's `rename` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
foreach(glob("vacation/*.jpg") as $image) {
  $tmpName = explode("_", $image);
  $tmpName = explode("~", $tmpName[1]);
  $md5 = md5($tmpName[0]);
  print "<p>{$md5}</p>";
  rename($image, $md5);
}
```